# Is this a suspicious upvoting pattern?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646900/grouped-uitableview-did-select-row-at-index-method from a new user is less than an hour old, is pretty poor quality, and has received 6 up-votes, which is nowhere near usual for the tag area it is in. Are we supposed to care, flag it, or ignore it?

I have flagged the question for moderator attention; was that the right thing to do?   Obviously, asking a question on meta about every dodgy question on Stack Overflow isn't the answer. I searched for previous questions about suspicious up-voting but didn't see any guidance.

Comment: Yeah, worth checking more accounts from same IP. @Avada - the downvotes are clearly from people seeing this post.

Comment: surely, what I meant is that this should probably be handled differently. probably better to flag it then to countervote on the question.

Comment: A second [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648079/possible-to-use-wildcards) by the same user is also showing odd voting. I've flagged it for the moderators.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that is an unusual pattern; not least, 2 of the votes were actually by the same user (**not** the OP) with two accounts (now merged).

As for why it got a spate of upvotes - it was mentioned in a chat. That *by itself* is not terrible, but indeed it should be upvoted *on the merits of the question, only*. I have responded as such in the chat.

Comment: Marc: How should behavior like this being treated in the future. As OP asks: is it appropriate to flag the question, or just let it be?

Comment: @Avada flagging for moderator attention (explaining your thoughts) would serve nicely

Comment: Can you check if [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/978265/v-jay) and [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/872321/v-jay) are the same?